# Get verb "base", singular non-possessive word, using OpenNLP

Tags: c#, opennlp

I'm considering using the [C# implementation of OpenNLP](https://github.com/AlexPoint/OpenNlp) in my project.

There are two main things I'd like to do.

1. Get the "base" form of a verb.

For example:

```
Input                                          Verb(s)           Desired Verb Base(s)
They were caught running away from the scene   caught, running   catch, run
The incident occurred last night               occurred          occur
We are planning some new features              planning          plan
```

2. Getting the singular, non-possessive, etc. form of a word.

For example:

```
Input      Desired output
cars       car
vehicle's  vehicle
knives     knife
feet       foot
```

Are these possible using OpenNLP, or is there another way to do this? (This is for English only).

Comment: Two things: 1) I believe in your last example, _"are planning"_ is a conjugation of _"to plan"_; there's really only one verb there.  2) Asking for advice about tools is one of the things on the "do not ask on Stackoverflow" list

Comment: Edited to fix that 